# Shopify Liquid - Hide metafield when it is empty

Tags: if-statement, shopify, liquid

I have the metafield that I'm struggling to hide when it has the value is taken out. The code below works up until the metafield has a value added and then is removed.

```
          {% if product_metafields.custom.preorder_end_date != blank %}
            <button id="preorder-date" class="button-primary">
              <span>{{ product_metafields.custom.preorder_end_date | date: "%d/%m/%Y" }}</span>
            </button>
          {% elsif selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
            <button id="quantity-btn" class="button-primary">
              <span>In Stock</span>
            </button>
          {% elsif selected_or_first_available_variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 %}
            <button id="quantity-btn" class="button-primary disabled">
              <span>Sold Out</span>
            </button>
          {% endif %}
```

Note: I have also tried this without the != blank

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was, the app 'Smart Product Filter & Search' needed to sync data with Shopify so that it was up-to-date.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).